# What is the ACF plot of $x_t = 0.9 x_{t-2} + w_t$

Tags: r, time-series, autoregressive, acf-pacf

I am just learning time series,

and I am wondering about the following AR(2) model:

$x_t = 0.9 x_{t-2} + w_t, w_t \sim N(0, \sigma_w^2)$

Please show me the plot of its Autocorrelation Function,

or you can rather plot it in R.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example with $n = 300$ values, where
$X_1 = 5, X_2 = 4,$ and, $W_i \stackrel{indep}{\sim}
\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=100, \sigma=2).$ A history plot and
and ACF plot from R are shown.

The first bar in the ACF plot is the autocorrelation of lag 0; of course it is $1.$ Autocorrelations inside the
horizontal lines are not considered significant.

```
set.seed(408)
m = 300;  x = numeric(m);  x[1]=5;  x[2]=4
for (i in 3:m) {
 w = rnorm(1, 0, 2)
 x[i] = .9*x[i-2] + w  }
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
 plot(x, type="l"); abline(h=0,col="green") 
 acf(x)
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

[image]